# how do i increment a number in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here's the problem i tried to increment using traditional programming way and I got this error.

**Error at MongooseError.ValidationError** and **at Array.forEach**

These errors are the results of these codes

The Cart Schema

```
var CartSchema = Schema({
  owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  prices: [Number],
  items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}],
  total: Number,
});
```

Error is at `cart.prices.forEach`

```
Cart.findById({ _id: cartId }, function(err, cart) {
        cart.prices.forEach(function(price) {
          console.log(price);
          cart.total += price;
        });
});
```

My goal is to loop through a `prices` array which is `[99,33,44,55]` and put it `cart.total` as the sum, but the problem is `cart.total += price` operation doesn't work as it produces the errors above. Please Help

Comment: are you sure `cart.prices` returned an array? check before your `forEach` loop